# Visual Studio 2017, how to include with <>?

Tags: c++, linker, include

I'm trying to use a C++ pdf library in my project.

It uses a bunch of project which I compiled into few .lib files and added to my project. Everything works.

However when I include a file which uses the FreeType2 library (PDFUsedFont.h) to use it, it gives me an error, in this line:

```
#include <ft2build.h>
```

I know the folder where the file ft2build.h is located, and it's being referenced a lot in the FreeType2 project.

I tried to add this folder in: 
- c/c++->other include folders, 
- VC++ folders -> Other inclusion folders, 
- linker->input->other dependencies.

Comment: Linker has nothing to do with dependencies. I.e. you modified the wrong path. The include path of the C++ *compiler* settings is what should contain the base location of your added include headers.

Comment: You should add folder path to C/C++ -> `Additional include directories`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the replies.

The mistake was I was modifying the wrong profile (!). Thanks again :)